# C++ vector push_back empty braces

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've seen code like

```
struct A {
  int m;
};

vector<A> vec;
vec.push_back({});
```

My question is:
What's the difference between `vec.push_back({});` and `vec.push_back(A{})`? Why can we omit `A` in `A{}`?

Comment: Add a version with vec.emplace_back() for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between `vec.push_back({});` and `vec.push_back(A{})`?

There isn't any, in this case.

> Why can we omit `A` in `A{}`?

You are instantiating a `vector` to hold `A` elements.  Thus its overloaded [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) methods will accept `const A&` and `A&&` input parameters.  Modern C++ standards provide [initialization rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) that let the compiler deduce that `{}` used in those contexts will construct an `A` object, which is why you don't need to specify the type in `A{}` explicitly.

FYI, `vector` also has [`emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) methods that you should use instead of pushing an empty `{}`:

```cpp
vector<A> vec;
vec.emplace_back();
```

Comment: I wouldn't say instead of. Push and emplace serve different purposes, and should be used accordingly.

Comment: @sweenish sure, but *in this example*, there is no benefit to using `push_back({})` over `emplace_back()`

Comment: That's an important caveat, *in this example*. I've seen people advocate for emplace as a wholesale replacement. It's not unpopular in the C++ blog circles. Sure, it might make sense most of the time, but I've seen too many posts where people give bad advice just so their headline can be more click-baity.

Comment: @sweenish vector::emplace should not be called with a member of the container, because it doesn't pay for handling that. I don't think there is anything else interesting...

Comment: @Deduplicator Could you explain a little more about "vector::emplace should not be called with a member of the container"? Do you mean we should not do `vec.emplace(vec.end(), anotherVec[5])`?

Comment: @llxxee No, I mean for `std::vector<T> v;`, `v.push_back(v[0])` is fine, while `v.emplace_back(v[0])` is UB unless you ensure no reallocation. `v.insert(v.begin(), v[0])` is fine, while `v.emplace(v.begin(), v[0])` is UB. Emplacing elements from an unrelated other vector is always fine.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think this is something the OP needs to worry about. I have never seen anyone try to push/emplace a copy of an existing element into the same vector. It would be extremely rare if such a thing would ever be needed. And like you said, it is UB only if a reallocation occurs, and there are ways to avoid that.

Comment: @Deduplicator How is emplacing a member of a same vector different from emplacing a member of another vector? Won't `v.emplace_back(v[0])` first construct a vector element using `{v[0]}` and then do reallocation?

Comment: @llxxee the purpose of `emplace_back()` is to construct a new element directly in the array, passing its constructor the parameters passed to `emplace_back()`.  So, if `emplace_back()` has to reallocate the array, and the input parameter(s) refer to existing elements of the same `vector` being emplaced into, then the reallocation can/may invalidate those parameter(s) before they can be used by the new element's constructor. That is not the case when emplacing into a different vector